# what are the tradeoffs for setting: params.put(TrainingParameters.ITERATIONS_PARAM, "100");

Tags: opennlp

what are the tradeoffs for setting:

`params.put(TrainingParameters.ITERATIONS_PARAM, "100");`

What the settings 10  verse 100  or 1000 actually do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe `"100"` is the default. If I'm right it stands for the times of the `iterations` trough your trainingdata. So your training set is better with 100 `iterations` then 10.